# Proof that there are infinitely many sin values

Tags: proof-explanation

Prove that there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $sin(n)>\frac{1}{2}$ and infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $sin(n)<\frac{-1}{2}$.

Seems so simple and probably is but I'm having difficulty proving this. Proof by contradiction didn't work for me.

Someone please show me how this is done.

Comment: For which $x$ is $\sin x > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Adding to the previous comment: you should find an infinite union of disjoint intervals, but all of the same length - how long?

Comment: Just courius: how to prove the existence of infinit many natural numbers with $\sin(x)>0.9$? Or is there a number $c$ satisfying $0<c<1$ such that $\sin(n)>c$ is is only true for a finite number of naturals?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe You would do it in the exact same way as this problem I would imagine.

Comment: If $\sin(n)>\frac12$, that implies that $\pi-0.523598776+2\pi k\ge n\ge0.523598776+2\pi k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi<x<\frac{5\pi}{6}+2n\pi \,\forall\, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ I'm lost though. How do I use this?

Comment: These (open) intervals have length $5\pi/6-\pi/6 = 2\pi/3 > 2$ so they all definitely contain...

Comment: @Hasan See if you can show that for every value of $n$, there is an $x\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the inequality.  I'll see if I can do it later.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. I was thinking I had to some how prove there were infinite intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Let us note $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n = 2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is the closest integer from $x_n$?

How much is $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2} - 0.5} $?  $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2} + 0.5} $?